# Checking a semver restriction is greater than or equal to another semver restriction

Tags: rust, semantic-versioning

I want to enforce a dependency's version requirement in a cargo toml is greater than or equal to another restriction. In a way I want ordering operator between a [semver::VersionReq](https://docs.rs/semver/latest/semver/struct.VersionReq.html) and a [semver::Comparator](https://docs.rs/semver/latest/semver/struct.Comparator.html). Aka can the right hand side hold under the conditions of the left hand side.

For example 0.5 >= 0.4, 0.5.1 >= 0.4, * >= 100.100.100 etc. I was looking to implement this myself but got a bit scared of from the number of the possible combinations on [semver::Op](https://docs.rs/semver/latest/semver/enum.Op.html). I couldn't find any of this logic in the semver crate, is there any other crates that can do this?

Maybe there a simpler way to do this using the cargo resolver?

Comment: Is this different from [`VersionReq::matches`](https://docs.rs/semver/latest/semver/struct.VersionReq.html#method.matches)?

Comment: @isaactfa Yep, the matches compares against a [Version](https://docs.rs/semver/latest/semver/struct.Version.html) (not a VersionReq), which has to have minor and patch fields. In my case I only want to check the major and minor version (aka want to check 0.5 matches 0.5.* and 0.5.1) so I don't have a minor field.

Not sure if if I could create a Version with a zero as patch for this to work...